# Excel: Match Twice in Same Column

Tags: microsoft-excel

What is an Excel formula to search a column for a match, and then beginning at that row, find a another match within the same column. For example, imagine a column containing 1000's of letters.

A
B
C
B
D
...

I want to find the index, ideally absolute, of B that follows C.

Comment: If letters are in, say, cells A1 to A1000, then use formula =MATCH("C",OFFSET(A1:A1000,MATCH("C",A1:A1000,0),0),0)+MATCH("C",A1:A1000,0). From AllExperts.Com.

Comment: =MATCH("B",OFFSET(A1:A1000000,MATCH("C",A:A,0),0),0)+MATCH("C",A:A,0) ? If so, please repost as an answer so you can receive well deserved credit. Is there a way to specify bottom instead of A1000000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chuff's answer works for me and might well be the best approach but you could also use this "array" version that includes the whole column

`=MATCH("B",IF(ROW(A:A)>MATCH("C",A:A,0),A:A),0)`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

works in Excel 2007 or later

Comment: Wouldn't this run into trouble if there were no "C" in the column?

Comment: @chuff I think Bsalita wants to find the first "B" that comes after a "C" - don't know what should happen if there's no "C" - my version will give #N/A if there's no "C"....or no "B" after that "C"

Comment: The spreadsheet is computer generated and guaranteed to have C and guaranteed to have B following C.

Comment: Will the array formula work in LibreOffice? The spreadsheet needs to be cross-platform.

Comment: I don't usually use LibreOffice but when I tried the formula works but not with the whole column so it would be back to `=MATCH("B",IF(ROW(A1:A1000)>MATCH("C",A1:A1000,0),A1:A1000),0)` or similar

Comment: barry, thanks for the follow up. I too just tried LibreOffice and OpenOffice as well. Using LibreOffice (3.6.4.3), I also found A:A isn't supported. I tested with =MATCH("C",a:a,0), but =MATCH("C",a1:a1000000,0) works. LibreOffice seems to have some bugs related to INDIRECT(). My formula usage has risen in sophistication to the point that LibreOffice has a few blocking bugs. Worse is OpenOffice (3.4.1) which my spreadsheet has revealed to be chock full of bugs. Looks like I'm forced to stick with Excel exclusively until the others mature.

Answer (score 0):

If the column of letters is in, say, cells A1 to A1000, then to find "B" use formula:

```
=MATCH("B",OFFSET(A1:A1000,MATCH("B",A1:A1000,0),0),0)+MATCH("B",A1:A1000,0)
```

Will get back to you on how to change to remove hard reference to 1,000th row.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column which has the entries that shouldn't be identified twice. Then under **Data** tab click on the filter icon under **Advanced**. Select `unique entries only`.  Any entries entered more than once will not be shown!